# Proof that the unit circle is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_2)$ be a metric space.

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ be the points consisting of the unit circle. Prove that $S$ is closed.

My question is whether or not the proof given below is valid.

To show that $S$ is closed, it suffices to show that $S^c$ is open. $S^c$ is open if, for all elements $s_c \in S^c$, there exists a radius $r$, such that $B_r (s_c) \subseteq S^c$.

Consider an arbitrary point $s_c$. Let $r_{s_c} = \inf \{d(s_c, x): \forall x \in S\}$. Then the open ball $B_{r_{s_c}} (s_c)$ will not contain any elements of $S$ as it does not contain the closest point in $S$ to $s_c$. Therefore, the ball must be completely contained in $S^c$, so by definition $S^c$ is open which implies $S$ is closed.

Comment: Your proof is flawed: where have you used the fact $S$ is closed? (Hint: it's regarding $r_{s_c}$)

Comment: How do you know that $r_{s_c}\not= 0$

Comment: What if $r_{s_c} = |\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - 1|$?

Comment: Your proof doesn't use at all the definition of $S$, that should be a red flag.

Comment: How do you know $inf\{d(s_c, x)\}> 0$?  And how would this proof work of $S$ were open... say $S = (0,1)$.  Let $s_c \in (0,1)^c$ and let $r_{s_c} = \inf\{d(x_c,x)\}$.  Then the open ball $B_{r_{s_c}}(s_c)$ will contain no points of $S=(0,1)$.  So $(0,1)$ is closed.

Comment: Perhaps an overkill solution is to note that $\theta \mapsto (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and maps therefore maps the compact set $[0, 2\pi]$ to a compact set. Therefore the unit circle is compact, and in particular closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:** $\qquad$ Consider the function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0, \infty)$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$. The map $f$ is a polynomial, hence continuous. The set $\{1\}$ is closed (with respect to the usual topology on $[0, \infty)$) and therefore your set $S = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed.

**Solution 2:** $\qquad$ Consider a sequence $(x_n, y_n) \in S$ converging to some limit $(x, y)$. Since $t \mapsto t^2$ is a continuous function:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = (\lim_n x_n)^2 + (\lim_n y_n)^2 = \lim_n~(x_n^2 + y_n^2) = 1. 
$$
And so $(x, y) \in S$.

**Solution 3:** $\qquad$ Let $z_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ and put $r_0^2 = x_0^2 + y_0^2$. Suppose that $z_0 \not \in S$, equivalently, $r_0^2 \neq 1$. We assume that $r_0 = 1 - \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon > 0$ (the case $r_0^2 > 1$ is similar). Consider the open ball $B(z_0, \epsilon/100)$, say. The triangle inequality implies that if $(x, y) \in B(z_0, \epsilon/ 100)$, then $x^2 + y^2 < 1$. Hence, $B(z_0, \epsilon/ 100) \subset S^c$, and $S$ is therefore closed.

Answer (score 0):

As several of the comments have noted, you utilise the fact that $S$ is closed when you speak of "the closest point in S to s_c". The existence of such a closest point requires that $S$ be closed. Furthermore, there can be more than one closest points (i.e. from the origin), so "the closest point in S to s_c" isn't always well-defined.

I would recommend proving the following theorem: let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous function, and let $V \subseteq Y$ be closed. Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed. Then, apply this to the definition of the circle.

If you are just learning analysis, then you should take $X$ and $Y$ to be metric spaces and show a related theorem: if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous (using the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuous) and $U \subseteq Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Then, use this theorem to prove the above one about the inverse image of closed sets.

If you have some topological background, you will recognise the above theorem as the definition of a continuous function. That is, a function $f : X \to Y$ satisfies the property that for every open $U \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open iff $f$ is continuous. You should definitely prove both directions using the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuity at some point in your mathematical life.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about your argument would apply equally well to any set.

And the error is assuming $r_s\inf\{d(s_c,x)\} > 0$.  If $S$ is *not* closed.  And $s_c$ is a limit point of $S$ *not*  in $S$ then $r_x = \inf\{d(s_c,x)\} = 0$ (That's *almost* the definition of limit point; in fact it is *completely* equivalent to the definition) and $B_{r_{s}}(s_c) = \emptyset$.

So that just won't work.  So will have to do something involving the *properties* of $S$.

Suppose $s_0= (x_0, y_0),s_1=(x_1,y_1) \not \in S$.  Then $x_0^2 + y_0^2 \ne 1$.  We can do two cases if $x_0^2 + y_0^2 > 1$ and if $x_1^2 + y+1^2 < 1$.

The intuition is simple.  If $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = R>1$ we let $d= R-1> 0$ we find some radius $r$ based on $d$ and we show $B_r(s)$ is so that for all $(v,w)\in B_r(s)$ and $v^2 + w^2 = 1$ is a contradiction.

It's the frigging *algebra* that is hard.